# Image not viewable using C# libraries viewable in ImageJ or ImageJ online have tried ImageMagick and ImageSharp and System.Drawing

Tags: c#, imagemagick, tiff, imagej, imagesharp

I have a file that I can view in ImageJ but most software just shows it in black. I am trying to view it in C# but it just comes up black, it is also not viewable in paint but I can view it in INcarta and ImageJ. The file is a 16 bit tiff that seems to have LZW compression

I am trying to use ImageSharp to decode this image and then show it as a bitmap. Here is a link to the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Xotc-2CJ6HkEJDysfKBkjClkU1OGiyQ/view?usp=sharing

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToDisplay1);



        SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffDecoder decoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffDecoder();
        SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffEncoder encoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffEncoder();
        SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image? image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(data, decoder);




        System.Drawing.Bitmap bMap;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(ms, encoder);
            bMap = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
```

I have also tried ImageMagickQ16

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fileToDisplay1);
                
                var decoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffDecoder();
                var encoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffEncoder();
                //encoder.BitsPerPixel = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.TiffBitsPerPixel.Bit16;
                var image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(data, decoder);
                MagickImage im2;



               using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(ms, encoder);
                    im2 = new MagickImage(ms.ToArray());
                }



               //im2.Depth = 16;
                //im2.Grayscale();
                im2.AutoLevel();



               return im2.ToBitmap();
```

The File Looks like this: in ImageJ but is black when I upload it or when I try to use other software.
[image]

I I have commented out other things I have tried

Comment: Your code to decode the image using ImageMagik is junk. You should be loading the image directly not using an encoded source from ImageSharp.

Comment: I know I am screwing around because I can't get it to work under any circumstances, It seems like both ImageSharp and ImageMagick have the same problem, they are displaying these images in black and white but they are not black and white images. Also that comment doesn't help me at all, when I feed the image directly to either library I don't get a grayscale

it's the same with System.Drawing, I don't know how to display this image in C#

Comment: You can't expect people to help you if the information provided is incomplete or incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick identify -verbose thinks your data is binary, just black and white.  So there is some error in Imagemagick.

```
Image:
  Filename: mystery.tif
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 2040x2040+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Bilevel
  Base type: Grayscale
  Endianness: LSB
  Depth: 16/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    gray: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 4161600
    Gray:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: -3
      skewness: 0
      entropy: 0
  Colors: 1
  Histogram:
       4161600: (0,0,0) #000000000000 gray(0)
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: gray(255)
  Border color: gray(223)
  Matte color: gray(189)
  Transparent color: gray(0)
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 2040x2040+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: LZW
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2022-09-27T00:43:06+00:00
    date:modify: 2022-09-27T00:42:39+00:00
    date:timestamp: 2022-09-27T00:43:25+00:00
    signature: 28f00fa3c1987b7b8f92961ef3a2d442cca23dbbb7c568b8908cc2fa2271de60
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: min-is-black
  Artifacts:
    filename: mystery.tif
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 48240B
  Number pixels: 4161600
  Pixels per second: 84.8629MB
  User time: 0.060u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.049
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.12-64 Q16 aarch64 17467 https://legacy.imagemagick.org
```

Mac Preview, GraphicConverter and Photoshop can read your image, but the gray levels are very low for a 16-bit range. Thus they appear at first glance as black. If the image dynamic range is stretched, the features show up.

But this does not work with Imagemagick since it thinks the data is binary and as such all the data values being very low have been put into the black bin.

Post and error to the Imagemagick web site at https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues

This is either a bug in Imagemagick or your file is malformed according to the tiff documentation. The IM developers will need to decide which.

Comment: in general i'm just trying to find out if I can view this image in C# I've tried other libraries like ImageSharp, and the built in System.Drawing.

The Java Library ImageJ handles this fine, so I don't think it's a problem with the tif specification, I just need to find a C# library that doesn't treat these as binary

Comment: It can be a problem with the tif specification since Imagemagick follows that specification very strictly, whereas ImageJ may ignore issues with the specification and open it anyway. Please post to the Imagemagick web site so this can be fixed if it is a bug

Comment: this picture was taken by a major commercial product used in thousands and thousands of places, so it's possible but this isn't just someone with a camera there are millions of photos like this being taken

Comment: Can you identify the major commercial product?  Nevertheless, they might not be following the standards fully, since tiff was made to customize. On the other hand, it could be an Imagemagick bug.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the TiffDecoder will decode images as `Rgba32` when using the non-generic API, (*something we can look into updating for v3 based upon the bit depth*), so you will not be capturing the image information since you are squashing 16bpp info into 8bpp.

Currently you can use `Image.Identify(...)` to determine the correct bit depth and make intelligent decoding choices, however, given that you know this image is grayscale and has a high dynamic range let's just decode it using `L16` (*16bit single luminance component*) and then stretch the histogram using the newly added method for V3. https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/pull/2235

```cs
using Image<La16> image = Image.Load<La16>(...);
image.Mutate(x => x.HistogramEqualization(new()
{
    LuminanceLevels = 65536,
    Method = HistogramEqualizationMethod.AutoLevel
}));
image.SaveAsPng(...)
```

The result is as expected.

[image: DecodeMystery_L16_mystery]

```
PM> Install-Package SixLabors.ImageSharp -Version 3.0.0-alpha.0.52 -Source https://www.myget.org/F/sixlabors/api/v3/index.json
```