# How to Display this image in C#

Tags: c#, image, file, photo, grayscale

I have an image https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Xotc-2CJ6HkEJDysfKBkjClkU1OGiyQ/view?usp=sharing that is GrayScale but every library I have tried, ImageMagick, ImageSharp, System.Drawing seem to interpret it as black and white, but when you open it in ImageJ or Photoshop or Incarta or many other software you can clearly see it is grayscale.

can anyone help me find a way to display this image? here is something I've tried but i've tried almost a dozen different things

```
TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder();
encoder.PhotometricInterpretation = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Tiff.Constants.TiffPhotometricInterpretation.BlackIsZero;


SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image image = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(mysteryTiff);

PixelTypeInfo pixType = image.PixelType;
// Stretches the image to fit the pictureBox.
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();

image.SaveAsTiff(stream, encoder);
stream.Position = 0;
MagickImage magickImage = new MagickImage(stream);

pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1200, 1200);
pictureBox1.Image = magickImage.ToBitmap();
```

Can anyone display this image correctly. It will display correctly when uploaded to

[image]

Comment: Technically, B&W is the same as greyscale.  If an image was only B&W then it would literally only have those 2 colours in it, but B&W images all have scales of grey.  https://www.phototraces.com/b/grayscale-vs-black-and-white-vs-monochrome/#:~:text=In%20essence%2C%20%E2%80%9Cgrayscale%E2%80%9D%20and,scale%20of%20shades%20of%20gray.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of "16-bit greyscale isn't supported." For some reason that specific format is not supported on a lot of different things. I work with lots of medical imaging that uses 16- and 12-bit greyscale, it's a pain to deal with. Magick.NET has a specific nuget package for dealing with 16-bit values that seems to work - any of the Magick.NET-Q16 packages.

Comment: That package works for most images but not for this microscope and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

What you have there, according to the image tag directory, is a 2024x2024 16-bpp greyscale LZW-compressed extended TIFF. It even opens in some software, which proves that it's not malformed. So far so good.

Now here's where it breaks down: 16-bpp greyscale is not supported by a lot of things. The 'why' is mildly convoluted, having to do largely with "but we all use 8 bits per channel, and so does the hardware, so why bother", but the end result isn't: if you want to use anything above 8 bits per channel, you'll either have to find something that will do the work for you or convert the data to 8-bpp at some point.

Even when the file format explicitly support 16-bpp greyscale (TIFF and PNG for instance), most libraries tend not to support either read or write in that format because it is so rarely used that they don't bother to implement it. I ended up writing my own PNG encoder for 16-bpp greyscale images (converted from 12-bpp and 16-bpp XRAY images), but the images aren't viewable in most programs that supposedly support the full PNG standard.

In this case your best option is probably going to be to write a conversion of your own for this type of file. Assuming that the same format (16-bpp, LZW-compressed) is produced by the source application every time, it shouldn't be too difficult to convert the pixel buffer to 8-bpp and save out as TIFF, PNG or whatever you like. You'll lose half of your greyscale (depth) resolution, but for display purposes they're not going to help much anyway. It only really matters when there's a good reason to retain the full range of values.

Comment: in this instance we are feeding this image into a machine learning/A.I. pipeline, a large part of the reason for buying a better microscope is we can take images with better resolution and see more minute differences. 

We can turn the microscope down/have it take 8 bit images but that destroyed the point

also there is no way of knowing what the A.I. models believe are significant differences, so this is data we really can't afford to lose. These images are not for display, we only need look at them because we often need to manipulate them before sending them into the pipeline.

Comment: That's unfortunate. IrfanView will display the images but not edit them. If you're writing the code yourself you might have to do all of your editing on a 16-bit buffer then convert-on-display. You might be able to use `Magick.NET-Q16` to do the read/write of the files though.

Comment: there is a bug in Magick.Net-Q16 that prevents this but they are working on a fix

Comment: ImageSharp loads the image just fine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73862507/427899